# Future Population Prediction using WorldPop Data with Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I would like to adapt this code to my area of ​​study, but an error in Parameter 'image' is required. Can anybody help me. The area in question is located in Paraíba-Brazil, I am using data from "FAO GAUL 500m: Global Administrative Unit Layers 2015, First-Level Administrative Units", to locate the study area and to forecast the population, I am using the data from "WorldPop Global Project Population Data: Estimated Residential Population per 100x100m Grid Square". Here's the link to the video I used as a basis for the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtwdOgnC5Rg&t=549s

```
//Obter limite da área de estudo
var area_estudo = gaul1.filter(ee.Filter.inList('ADM1_NAME', ['Sumé', 'Serra Branca', 'Amparo', 'Prata', 'Monteiro', 'Ouro Velho']));
Map.addLayer(area_estudo, {}, 'Área de Estudo');
 
//Visualização de dados da população
var popVis = { min: 0, max: 100, palette: ['black', 'red', 'white'] };

//Dados de população Municipios do worldpop
var javaPop = worldPop.filterBounds(area_estudo).filter(ee.Filter.eq('country', 'IDN')).map(function(feat){
return feat.clip(area_estudo); // Dados do clipe para apenas oara a parte da área de estudo
});
print(javaPop); // Imprima todos os dados da população
Map.addLayer(javaPop.sort('system:time_start', false).first(), popVis, 'População de 2020'); // Mostrar dados de 2020

//Reduzir a população da região 2020
var javaPop2020Reduce = javaPop.sort('system:time_start', false).first().reduceRegions({
scale: 100,
collection: area_estudo,
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
}).map(function(feat){
return feat.set('Pop_2020', ee.Number(feat.get('sum')).toUint32(), 'sum', null);
});

//Tabela de população
var chartPop2020 = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
features: javaPop2020Reduce,
xProperty: 'ADM1_NAME',
yProperties: ['Pop_2020']
}).setChartType('Table');
print(chartPop2020);

//banda do ano
var popYearBand = javaPop.map(function(image){
var yearBand = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('year'))).rename('year');
return image.addBands(yearBand).select(['year', 'population']).toUint32();
});

//Regressão linear
var regression = popYearBand.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

//Prever 2023
var pop2023 = regression.select('scale').multiply(2023).add(regression.select('offset'));
Map.addLayer(pop2023, popVis, 'Previsão da População para 2023'); // Mostrar dados de 2023

//Prever 2050
var pop2050 = regression.select('scale').multiply(2050).add(regression.select('offset'));
Map.addLayer(pop2050, popVis, 'Previsão da População para 2050'); // Mostrar dados de 2050

//Reduzir a população da região 2023
var javaPop2023Reduce = pop2023.reduceRegions({
scale: 100,
collection: javaPop2020Reduce,
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
}).map(function(feat){
return feat.set('Pop_2023', ee.Number(feat.get('sum')).toUint32(), 'sum', null);
});

//Reduzir a população da região 2050
var javaPop2050Reduce = pop2050.reduceRegions({
scale: 100,
collection: javaPop2023Reduce,
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
}).map(function(feat){
return feat.set('Pop_2050', ee.Number(feat.get('sum')).toUint32(), 'sum', null);
});

//Tabela de população
var chartPop2050 = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
features: javaPop2050Reduce,
xProperty: 'ADM1_NAME',
yProperties: ['Pop_2020', 'Pop_2023', 'Pop_2050']
}).setChartType('Table');
print(chartPop2050);
```